# Why onchange function not called when checkbox changed using checked property

Tags: javascript, events

Checkbox is handled using another button.

1. If I directly click on checkbox then the onchange triggers.
2. But when I change the check box using button, onchange(i.e. show() method) is not called.

```js
var checkbox=document.getElementById("x");
var button=document.getElementById("y");

button.addEventListener("click",function(){
checkbox.checked== true
?checkbox.checked=false
:checkbox.checked=true;

})


var show=function(){
window.alert("onchange called");
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='xyz' id='x' onchange="show()">

<br>

<button id='y'>Toggle Checkbox</button>
```

How to call `show()` method if button is clicked.

Comment: Changing an attribute or property programmatically does not trigger a change event. However, you can do that manually

Comment: that means, i need to call show method when button is clicked, and not when checkbox changes.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `checked` property of a checkbox doesn't trigger a `change` event from that checkbox. You will have to dispatch it yourself:

```js
y.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // toggle the checkbox
  x.checked = !x.checked;
  // and manually dispatch a change event on the checkbox
  let change = new Event('change');
  x.dispatchEvent(change);
})

x.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log(x.checked);
})
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='xyz' id='x' />

<br>

<button id='y'>Toggle Checkbox</button>
```

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation. I was a bit surprised I couldn't find a canonical one - it seems all questions about triggering a change event were tagged in jQuery and all the answers were using that, instead of just JS.

Comment: The same works analogously for other input types when you programmatically set the `value`.

Comment: @JonathanGagne You miss the point of the `show()` function. It is there only to check if a change event occurs (which my code does by applying `addEventListener()` to the checkbox itself). Also the question is not *How can I make a programmatic change of a checkbox call show()* but *Why is onchange not triggered by a change of checkbox checked property*.

Comment: @JonathanGagne It seems you're upset and getting cynical. Why is that? It's just that I think you missed the point of the question. And you keep insisting to miss it. The core of OP's question is "Why does programmatic changing of a checkbox state not trigger a change event from that checkbox". How is your answer adressing any of that?

Comment: @connexo I'm not upset or cynical my friend. Your solution is the most convenient way to do it. However, I think about the OP question first. Question: How to call `show()` method if button is clicked. Answer: Triggers a click instead to change the checkbox value. Solution: Change one line. I do believe that we should help to understand their code and not showing them the best way to make it. We have to keep the dev pace.